# Javascript split result simplify

Tags: javascript, split

Is there a way to make this code more simplified?

```
<input type="text" id="tags" />

var splittext = document.getElementById('tags').value.split(' ');
if (document.getElementById('tags').value.split(' ').length < 2 || splittext[1] == '') {
   alert("Two tags required.");
}
```

is there another way to make

```
 splittext[1] == ''
```

be like

```
document.getElementById('tags').value.split(' ').something[1]
```

to avoid using the line

```
var splittext = document.getElementById('tags').value.split(' ')
```

The purpose of this is when a user inputs **one** tag and made **a space after** it, the split detects 2 values which i would like to avoid the space being counted as another tag because that would be like, uhm, cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim first, and split on any number of white space characters:

```
if (document.getElementById('tags').value.trim( ).split(/\s+/).length < 2) {
    alert("Two tags required.");
}
```

You will need to create the `String.trim` function if you want to support some versions of IE though... but it's a useful function to have. Put this in a utility js file, or just at the top of your js:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah :

```
var g= document.getElementById('tags').value.split(/[ ]+/)

if (g.length==2)  // ok.....
```

http://jsbin.com/ovibef/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this to avoid making multiple calls to the same dom element(you are splitting the same thing twice)

```
var splittext = document.getElementById('tags').value.split(' ');
if (splittext.length < 2 || splittext[1] == '') {
   alert("Two tags required.");
}
```

This is the whole point of using variables, to avoid calling the same function(with the same results) multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var elem=document.getElementById('tags').value;
if(elem.indexOf(' ')>-1 && elem.split(' ').length>=2) {
    alert('Worked!');
} else if(!elem || elem.indexOf(' ')<0) {
    alert('Two tags required.');
}
```